# Python sorted method treats two digit string as three digit string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I'm using python 2.7.6, and am having trouble sorting a json object using *sorted* (in the form of a list of dictionaries).

When I first inspected the sorted output, it seems like the list was only partially sorted, as there were smaller numbers in between. On closer inspection, it appears that the two digit numbers like 93 were being treated like 93X. With this insight, the sorted output then appeared correct.

No idea why this is happening. At first, I thought it might be because I did not convert the json object to a python object properly before sorting. However, I doubt this was the issue as *json.load* in the code will deserialize the json object into a python object.

[Here's the jsbin](http://jsbin.com/celiga/1/edit?js) of the "sorted" output. I've tried re-sorting the sorted list and it gives me the exact same result.

Code below:

```
import json

json_data = open('test.json')
data = json.load(json_data)

results = sorted(data, key = lambda item : item["AveragePoints"], reverse = True)

with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(results, outfile);

json_data.close()
```

Comment: Maybe: `key = lambda item : float(item["AveragePoints"])` ?

Comment: Strings are sorted lexicographically so "100" is less than "2" in the same way "astronomical" is less than "big".

Comment: This issue is because your json is incorrect. Integers should be encoded as such, that is `"AveragePoints":999`, not `"AveragePoints":"999"`. Fix that, and your code will work fine! (`float` works too, but it's always better to heal the cause and not the symptoms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `AveragePoints` to a number before sorting, like this

```
sorted(data, key = lambda item : float(item["AveragePoints"]), reverse = True)
```

Now the `AveragePoints` values will be compared as floats, so that the sorting will be proper.

**Note:** If you are sure that the `AveragePoints` will be an integer always, you can use `int` function instead of `float`.

Comment: Thanks [thefourtheye](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1903116/thefourtheye), that worked. I did not convert initially as the [python docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)  had some examples which could sort strings, and I guessed that worked for string numbers as well.

Comment: @YanYi Try this `print(sorted(["1", "10", "01"]))`. You will understand it better, I guess